# angularJS Hide button and textboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which I have two buttons.

1st for insert 
2nd for update
and on the click of any of these buttons I want to open a modal and it is working good.

modal is poped up after I click (either on insert or update)

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"><p style="color:red; text-align:center;">Don't Leave Empty Field Please Fill 'N.A' There !!</p></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<select>
<option>Insert Text Box</option>
<option>Update Text box</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="insert">
<input type="text" name="update">
    </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Insert</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

But if a user click `insert` or `update button` in `modal-footer` must be `hide`

and in modal if user chooses insert in dropdownlist `update textbox` must be hide and if a user chooses update `insert textbox` must be hide.

Comment: Use `ng-hide` or `ng-show` in your button.

Comment: i need to use ng-hide and ng-show with if else but i don't know how to do it in angularjs

Comment: Why the heck is there a C# tag? Javascript doesn't go anywhere near that.

Comment: my whole project is on c#

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ng-click directive to the two buttons and add a method to close the modal, like this:

```
<button ng-click="closeModal()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Insert</button>
```

Most likely the modal you are using already has a method for this available. Otherwise you would need to handle the closing part in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in your controller's data the information and then use the ngShow directive ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)) to display one or the other.

Here's an example if you have a controller named *ctrl* with a *updateModal* boolean.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!ctrl.updateModal">Insert</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="ctrl.updateModal">Update</button>
```

Then you'll have to update this boolean value when you open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scope variable to keep track of the last button that was pressed, and use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#!) to only display the desired button.

However, if chances are you're going to eventually customize the modal dialog further, it's going to get messy. If I were you, I'd sacrifice a bit of typing and create two modal dialogs. Then, I'd have the action buttons show each their associated modal.